# is a while(true) loop cheaper than posting a handler.postDelayed() every X ms

Tags: android, while-loop, android-handler

I am making an android app in which i need to monitor the sound levels from the mic. My logic works if I'm taking the sound level value every 50-100ms. The way I see it...to monitor these values I have two options

1) A while loop

```
while(true){
  //get sound levels and do my logic
}
```

2) A handler that reposts its self every let's say 50 ms to check the sound levels

```
final Handler handler3=new Handler();
handler3.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //get sound levels and do my logic
        handler.postDelayed(this, 50);
    }                   
}, 50);
```

It seems cheaper (in battery and cpu power) to me to use the handler solution. But I don't know much about the inner workings of java and android and how expensive it is to post a handler so I just wanted to make sure i do the right thing in the end. Also if there is a cheaper solution i'd be glad to hear it

Comment: Please don't put my phone into a tight loop.

Comment: If you have another way in mind to constantly get the microphone's aplitude value I'd be glad to hear it! That's the purpose of the question...improving my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop is WAY cheaper than handler, but you have to implement it in a separate thread with appropriate sleep calls otherwise it will block your app main thread, making your app unresponsive. Additinally it requires synchronisation to access shared objects.

The Handler.postDelayed() function takes some CPU, but it has a benefit that no thread synchronisation is necessary if you use it.

Comment: the loop is done in a service in the background. It has no UI to be blocked. It can be stopped bye the user at will ofcourse. And it is not meant for continuous use at all times rather than activating for a while and then deactivating. But ofcourse it would be better if it is cheap enough to keep it activated for long periods of time without affecting battery life. That is why i ask this question here.

Comment: Then use the loop. Handler does take some time. I have seen it while profiling my apps, high enough in the usage list to notice it :)

Comment: I see..thnx for the info. Just for general knowledge...Do you know if the expense of the handler is at the creation and posting it or during it's runtime?

Comment: No, the actual profiler entry was Handler.postDelayed(). So the call to place the runnable into the queue. The runnable itself only has the procedure entry / exit points as overhead, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

I think that depends on what you want to do exactly.
Is there anything else you would like to do during the loop?
When the loop runs your app cannot do anything else. It just loops round and round.

You might want to have some sort of button which can be pressed to stop listening.
You might want to have some graph which shows the noise or audio level.

In order to keep the UI running smoothly all the time, I would recommend to go for the handler-approach.
Your UI thread will then never be bothered by what's going on with the audio processing...

I'm not a so deep expert to be able to judge how much cheaper a while() loop is, but I think it's definitely cheaper - but you have above mentioned drawback.
From programming point-of-view, it's also more complicated to work with handlers as you do multi-threading. You do not have multiple threads with the while() approach.

However, I would recommend to do the audio processing in a thread separate from the UI thread.

Comment: the loop is done in a service in the background. It has no UI to be blocked. It can be stopped bye the user at will ofcourse. And it is not meant for continuous use at all times rather than activating for a while and then deactivating. But ofcourse it would be better if it is cheap enough to keep it activated for long periods of time without affecting battery life. That is why i ask this question here.